# Angular CLI ng new project-one generates a folder called project-one and package-lock.json, why is package-lock.json outside of the project folder?

Tags: angular, angular-structural-directive

I am not sure why this is the new structure of Angular project, and I noticed when ng new try to create a workspace for multiple projects, this cli will generates a zip folder simultaneously. I am confused why this is good structure. Can anyone explain this to me? Thank you. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIvFh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCRuY.png)

I just followed the documentation but there isn't an explanation of these.